# Bundling issue on react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, react-scripts

In react js ui app, after building/bundling the application, in build/chunk js file, some repository url(like axios) got exposed. It's a security issue.  How to fix this issue. "react-scripts build and node scripts/postBuild.js" -I used for build.

Comment: Everything you put in your frontend will be exposed no matter what you do. You can make it a bit harder by using an uglifier but even then its still possible to de-uglify the code.

Answer (score 0):

Never hard code the full api address in the JS file, use package.json for the main url address, and use a constant file for all remaining address section. apply auth logic like tokens for the security on api section

Comment: I'm not hard coding anything.using package json for a axios dependency. In build axios npm repo url got exposed.

Comment: Update the react scripts version 5.0.0 resolved the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Update the react scripts version 5.0.0 resolved the above issue